# When i create an object from the class myTriangle using the first constructor i am having an error saying exception

Tags: java

`MyPoint` class:

```
public class Mypoint {    
    int x;
    int y;

    Mypoint() {
         x=0;
         y=0;
    }
    Mypoint(int x, int y) {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }
    public void setx(int x) {
        this.x=x;
    }
    public void sety(int y) {
        this.y=y;
    }
    public int getx() {
        return x;
    }
    public int gety() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setxy(int x, int y) {
        this.x=x ;
        this.y=y;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "X cordinate   : " +getx()
              +" Y coordinate: " + gety()+"\n";
    }
    public double distance(int x, int y) {
        int xdiff,ydiff;
        xdiff= this.x-x;
        ydiff= this.y-y;
        return Math.sqrt(xdiff*xdiff+ydiff*ydiff);
    }

    public double distance(Mypoint another) {
        int xdiff,ydiff;
        xdiff= this.x-another.x; 
        ydiff= this.y-another.y; 
        return Math.sqrt(xdiff*xdiff+ydiff*ydiff); 
    }
}
```

`myTriangle` class:

```
public class myTriangle {
    Mypoint point1;
    Mypoint point2;
    Mypoint point3;

    //when I'm using this constructor I'm having error
    myTriangle(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2,int x3,int y3) {
        point1.x=x1;
        point1.y=y1;

        point2.x=x2;
        point2.y=y2;

        point3.x=x3;
        point3.y=y3;
    }

    myTriangle(Mypoint p1,Mypoint p2, Mypoint p3) {
        point1=p1;
        point2=p2;
        point3=p3;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "Triangle @ \n" +point1.toString()+ point2.toString()+ point3.toString();
    } 
}
```

I got an exception when using this constructor:

```
myTriangle(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2,int x3,int y3)
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: "im having error" is *never* enough information. Additionally, please take some time to format your code properly. See http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: Yor variables point1 to point3 are never initialized. So you get an NPE.

Comment: Try access all your mypoint members with -> operator. point1.x=x1 change to point1->x=x1

Comment: @Solano there is no such thing as a `->` operator in Java

Comment: @AndréStannek Well, there _is_ a `->` operator (lambda in Java 8), but not that kind...

Comment: This topic was c++ 2 minutes ago..with the 2 members x and y as pointers

Comment: @tobias_k allright, sadly I did never work with Java 8. Nevermind :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize those `point` variables using the appropriate `Mypoint` constructor.

```
myTriangle(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2,int x3,int y3) {   
    point1 = new Mypoint(x1, y1);
    point2 = new Mypoint(x2, y2);
    point3 = new Mypoint(x3, y3);
}
```

Also, following Java coding conventions, better use class names `MyPoint` and `MyTriangle`.

Answer (score 0):

First: There already is a [Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) class in Java, that does exactly what your Class MyPoint does, try to not reinvent the wheel when you can use what the standard API does for you.

Second: There is a [Shape](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) class in Java, take a look at it.

Third: Languages have [conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) for naming, use them, they are not to be disregarded.

That said, when you construct a new Object, other Objects inside that one are not automatically initialized, you need to do so in the constructor. Your second constructor does exactly that. Your first one doesn't. 
You can either do this, it implements a constructor that initializes your variables:

```
myTriangle(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2,int x3,int y3) {   
    point1 = new Mypoint(x1, y1);
    point2 = new Mypoint(x2, y2);
    point3 = new Mypoint(x3, y3);
}
```

or this:

```
myTriangle(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2,int x3,int y3) {   
    this(new Mypoint(x1, y1), new Mypoint(x2, y2), new Mypoint(x3, y3);
}
```

it implements constructor that calls the other constructor. (It's not particularly useful, just pointing out something you CAN do) or you can delete the first constructor and always build myTriangle through the second one (I'd do this, since they are redudant).

Don't forget you can build myTriangle in your calling class like this:

```
myTriangle triangle = new myTriangle(new Point(x1, y1), new Point(x2, y2), new Point(x3, y3));
```